# I send a scheduled message to activemq broker but two message shown in web console

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

I wrote a simple `ActiveMQ` client program for produce a message as following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
{
    final ActiveMQConnectionFactory conFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
    final QueueConnection connection = conFactory.createQueueConnection();
    final Session session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    final Destination destination = new ActiveMQQueue("MJ_SAF");
    final MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);

    Message message = session.createTextMessage("test");
    message.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, 20);
    message.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_PERIOD, 1);
    message.setIntProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_REPEAT, 1);
    producer.send(message);
}
```

when this program executed I expect a message stored in scheduled part of `ActiveMQ` and after 20 second send for `MJ_SAF` queue but when I connect to web consol saw following result:

[image]

stored two messages at `MJ_SAF` and it's not correct but when I normally send message (without scheduling), I see a message in web console.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
{
    final ActiveMQConnectionFactory conFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
    final QueueConnection connection = conFactory.createQueueConnection();
    final Session session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    final Destination destination = new ActiveMQQueue("MJ_SAF");
    final MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);

    Message message = session.createTextMessage("test");
    producer.send(message);
}
```

by above code all things is nice:

[image]

I don't understand this behavior. Does anyone know reasons of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the property `ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_REPEAT` set to 1, so it will repeat 1 time giving you a total of 2 messages.

See [here](http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html) for the descriptions of the properties. As I understand it, your current set up will wait 20 milliseconds, publish 1 message, wait 1 millisecond, and publish a second message, then end.